# Partial differentiation of a function of three variable written in terms of a function of two variables.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have a function of three variables $u$ and a function of two variables $g$ satisfying:
\begin{align}
u(x,y,z) = g(xe^{-z},ye^{-z}).
\end{align}
How can I possibly find $u_x, u_y$ and $u_z$. When I tried I got:
\begin{align} 
u_x = g_x(xe^{-z},ye^{-z})e^{z}
\end{align}
and a similar expression for $u_y$. But for $u_z$ I am a bit confused. Please is my $u_x$ correct? also, How can I find $u_z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find it clearer if you write $g$ as $g(v, w)$ and its derivatives as $g_v(v, w)$ and $g_w(v, w)$. Then, for example,

$$\begin{eqnarray} \frac{du}{dx} & = & \frac{d}{dx} g(x e^{-z}, y e^{-z}) \\
& = & \frac{\partial g}{\partial v} \frac{dv}{dx} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial w} \frac{dw}{dx} \\
& = & g_v \frac{d}{dx}(x e^{-z}) + g_w \frac{d}{dx}(y e^{-z}) \\
& = & e^{-z} g_v(x e^{-z}, y e^{-z}) \end{eqnarray}$$

And this does line up with your expression for $u_x$. However, when you take the derivative with respect to $z$, neither of the terms will vanish because both inputs to $g$ depend on $z$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clairfication.

Comment: @ChristopherCharles An alternative notation is to use enumerated subscripts to indicate when the derivative with respect to the argument of a function, rather than a variable.  $$\begin{align}u(x,y,z) &= g(x\,\mathrm e^{−z},y\,\mathrm e^{−z})\\[1ex]u_x&=u_1(x,y,z)\\[1ex]&=(x\mathrm e^{-z})_x\,g_1(x\,\mathrm e^{-z},y\,\mathrm e^{-z})+(y\mathrm e^{-z})_x\,g_2(x\,\mathrm e^{-z},y\,\mathrm e^{-z})\\[1ex]&=\mathrm e^{-z}\,g_1(x\,\mathrm e^{-z},y\,\mathrm e^{-z})\end{align}$$ So you don't have to introduce new variables; but otherwise the same principle applies.